# nvim termenal ctrl + c not interupting, instead hanging

Tags: linux, cpu, neovim

when I try to call a keyboard interrupt in the nvim terminal emulator, my cpu usage goes very high and fluctuates a bunch, as seen in the photo:[my cpu usage before and after the interupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9VFm.png) also the whole terminal hangs and I have to force quit, does anyone else have this problem?

i tried to call an interupt using ctrl+c, and i expected for it to interrupt, but instead it hanged and my cpu usage skyrocketed